# Can't connect to Ubuntu server VM (VirtualBox) on local machine, can't seem to restart network manager either

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox, network-manager

A bit of background: This tiny project went from a curiosity to a "kind of" mandate at work (this is all just to set up a website sandbox). And so I created an Ubuntu (18.04.2) VM with VirtualBox and it seemed to install ok.

The docs and tutorials I have gathered up seem to be outdated because when I installed I was only given the option to install OpenSSH, and not LAMP (as seemed preferable from the docs I looked at). In fact I didn't see any choice other than OpenSSH, only further on selection for things like Powershell and such.

I changed from NAT to Bridged Connection.

And most docs say that I have to then restart the network. And here is the second oddity. No matter what command I use (pick one, gotten from here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux):

```
$ sudo netplan apply
$ sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
$ sudo service network-manager restart
$ sudo nmcli networking off
$ sudo nmcli networking on
```

Everything returns a "command not found" error.

However, I can change back and forth through the network options and do an *ifconfig* and I see that there are differences. So I assume that the network machine is picking up the changes.

Now the kicker, I can't access the VM through any browser. Firewall is off, but I always get a "connection timed out" error.

What steps might I have missed that keep this VM undiscoverable?

Network settings:

[image]

Comment: Silly question but you didn't also type the `$`, did you? That would give you `$: command not found.`

Comment: Ah, no, not at first. But after the number of errors, I cycled through all the permutations I could think of. It was really late. But in all seriousness, no, not in the tries that counted.

Comment: *"through any browser"* if you haven't installed / configured a web server, then you won't be able to connect via a browser. You should be able to connect using an SSH client though.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So I guess I should really be asking what else is left to install, and have to all the other components separately.

Comment: And so, when I try to install anything more, it can't resolve. `sudo apt update` fails with numerous "failed to fetch xxxxxxxxxxx Temporary failure resolving archive.ubuntu.com" errors. Should I by using the .iso as the optical drive? Or does this not matter?

Comment: This is starting to be out of scope of the original question.

Comment: ("should I be using the .iso as the optical drive?") No, by now you should have a network, and be able to reach `archive.ubuntu.com` and perform updates and installs. Please edit your question and add the network settings for the VM (from the host machine).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but do you mean the output from an `ifconfig`? Or what I put in the VM settings?

Comment: I mean information like this: https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/9860/VirtualBox%20Networking%20Settings.PNG

Comment: Added settings in question.

Comment: Update: The network I was on was blocking my VM. I switched to a different network and I was let through. I can install now. I will update with status/progress with my LAMP installation to possibly help any others who might be so beginner as to fall into my same global situation.